# What are the options when the mother of a 7 year old is imprisoned?

Tags: primary-schooler, communication, divorce, separation, mother

What are the options for explaining a (divorced) mother's absence to a 7 year old?  Should the child be told the truth? (Assume the crime is non-violent and financial.  Also assume the child has had a loving relationship with both parents, separately for the past several years.  The parenting plan has the child staying with the mother every other weekend; other times with the father.)

Are visitations by a 7 year old to an imprisoned mother generally considered by experts to be the best approach or are there other approaches that child experts suggest?

(The topic of telling children about a parent in prison was discussed here but without consideration of the age of the child: [Should children of incarcerated parents be told the truth?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/should-children-of-incarcerated-parents-be-told-the-truth))

Answer (score 13):

That question and answer you linked said everything about why you absolutely should tell the child the truth. At seven your grand is perfectly capable of understanding the concepts of right and wrong; understands making mistakes and also understands punishment.

The mother is paying for the mistake she made. If it is true, say that Mother is sorry and is trying to do better. You'll have to tell the truth about the crime, too. That could be a problem depending on the nature of the crime. Theft is a much more simple explanation than prostitution, but regardless truth is important. Do not make excuses, just tell the truth as kindly as you are able to.

Separate the person from the crime. Mother is not labelled by you. The crime might be named, but you do not call Mother a thief or a drug dealer. "Mom made a serious mistake. The judge put her in jail/prison for x amount of time. Mom is trying to fix this by being good in prison. She loves you and wishes she had not made that mistake."

I hope your grand does get to visit. If nothing else she'll see her mum is safe and that she still loves her daughter.

Encourage the relationship (unless custody was  refused or visitations refused.) Letters, drawings, visits and phone calls will all help. Take photos and report cards and examples of projects or school work that your grand can share with her mother. A journal that your grand can choose to share with Mother (or not share)  can help her with her feelings. She can draw, use photos and write things in her journal.

My daughter's birth mum and dad died. She had a journal that was really a decorated accordion file folder. She wrote, drew pictures and shared photos and 'shared' them with her Mummy and Daddy.  We do not pray but we do speak aloud our gratitude, and in addition she spoke to them every night before bed  -- just to tell them what she was doing. This was our 'key' to helping our child get past the trauma. You might try something like this for your granddaughter. We keep Mummy and Daddy alive by talking about them frequently. You can keep Mother as an active but absent family member in the same way.

Comment: This is also good advice if mom is committed to a long-term psychiatric facility. Interestingly, the stigma is probably worse for the mentally ill than the criminal; although visitation rights are better in a mental health facility, even for the criminally insane.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of things to consider to answer this question. OP states that the mother is incarcerated from a non-violent crime (which covers a huge range of things) but we don't have access to critical information. For instance, what was the relationship between Mother and Child prior to the arrest? Healthy? Loving? Abusive? Neglectful?  Did they live together, or apart, or part of the time? Was the child present when Mom was arrested, or did she just not show up at school to pick him/her up?  The sources (listed below) provide a number of things to consider:

1. I absolutely, firmly, agree that the child should be told that their
   Mother is in jail (for xx amount of time). Time might not be a fully
   understood concept for a 7yo. They may not be capable of
   understanding "two years", but "two birthdays" could make a lot more
   sense.
2. I'm wary of suggesting that a 7yo needs details about what their
   Mother did 'wrong'. A 7yo will not fully understand what or why this
   happened. I think most parents would agree that 7yo children fundamentally understand right from wrong,
   but they don't have any references for the gray areas between the
   black and white of breaking the law.  Leave that conversation for
   when the child is older.
3. If the Mother and Child are agreeable to visitation, then everything
   should be done to make it happen. It will help the child comprehend
   that "Mom" cannot come home just yet. But more importantly, it will
   help them move forward with their relationship. Visitation isn't the
   only way that their relationship can move forward. Consider
   (birthday and holiday) cards, letters, and gifts.
4. There are reasons not to have them see each other though. If the
       Mother lost her custody rights prior to her arrest. If the Mother was
       guilty of any type of neglect or abuse, even if the neglect or abuse
       was at the hands of someone else (ex: a boyfriend living in the
       home). If the Mother was actively involved in a dangerous lifestyle
       (drugs, prostitution, gang life). Extremes like those need to be evaluated individually.

[FAQs About Children of Prisoners](https://www.prisonfellowship.org/resources/training-resources/family/ministry-basics/faqs-about-children-of-prisoners/)
[Parent in Prison: How to Protect the Well Being of the Child](https://health.usnews.com/wellness/family/articles/2017-01-19/parent-in-prison-how-to-protect-the-well-being-of-the-child)

Comment: TY.  Based on the sources you cite, I found this one: 
https://www.sesamestreet.org/sites/default/files/media_folders/Images/Incarceration_Guide.pdf  (Sesame hired experts on this topic.)

Comment: Good sources, well done. But, "A 7yo will not fully understand what or why this happened. ...they don't have any references for the gray areas between the black and white of breaking the law." They understand the consequences of breaking rules at home. What support do you have for the statement that a child that age won't understand breaking the law? Is it not dependent on the law broken and the maturity of the child involved? The crime is a non-violent, financial one, not a murder.

Comment: @anongoodnurse You're taking my words out of context. I didn't say that a 7yo doesn't understand "breaking the law".  Children (in my socio-economic class) aren't taught specifics about the law. Did you raise your children differently? But then, most adults don't understand all of the laws on our books. That's why we hire lawyers.

Comment: Again, a post notice is earned when you make statements as fact. You say to be wary of telling the child about why the parent is incarcerated because 7 yo's "don't have any references for the gray areas". Please provide a source. As to your lawyer comment, we don't normally hire them after a crime because we don't understand we've broken the law, but because we want an expert negotiator. Hiring a lawyer before taking actions (e.g. drawing up a will) is a different matter. That's a red herring.

Comment: You are insisting I produce something that you are fully aware does not exist. There are no sources saying that children "know (or don't know), understand, and/or have real-life references for the gray areas of our legal system (in the U.S.)"  I believe this to be common sense. Most parents would agree that first and second graders are not being taught about our legal system through our public school curriculum. Again, your comments are another example that you are taking my words out of context.

Comment: There is literature available on the advisability of discussing or not discussing the crime committed by the parent with the child. This is what I'm asking for: a source to back up your statement that it's something their kids would not understand. False analogies help no one. Neither of your sources discuss this, so it's an unsupported statement written as fact. I would not comment if this were an unimportant, minor part of your answer.

Comment: @elbrant I think it might be better if you restructured your post some, to make clear what you're sourcing and what is your opinion (or, what you're stating as common knowledge but not coming from your sources).  Rather than summarizing your sources and then linking to them, I find it better to quote from the sources where possible, and where directly quoting is not possible, to use links to the sources (think the superscript numbers in academic articles) to indicate what you're specifically deriving from sources.

Comment: Otherwise, it appears that either you're not deriving anything from sources and are simply giving your opinion and then some further reading, or else that everything you say is coming from the sources - which it isn't, at least not in this case - and either way it weakens your post to other critical readers, and can (unintentionally) confuse other readers into thinking your opinions are sourced facts.

Comment: @anongoodnurse  You say there is literature available on the advisability of discussing a parent's crime.  Please point me to that literature.